# How to change the kernel max PID number?

Tags: linux, kernel, process, limit

The default PID max number is 32768. To get this information type:

```
cat /proc/sys/kernel/pid_max 
32768
```

or

```
sysctl kernel.pid_max
kernel.pid_max = 32768
```

Now, I want to change this number... but I can't. Well, actually I can change it to a lower value or the same. For example:

```
linux-6eea:~ # sysctl -w  kernel.pid_max=32768
kernel.pid_max = 32768
```

But I can't do it for a greater value than 32768. For example:

```
linux-6eea:~ # sysctl -w  kernel.pid_max=32769
error: "Invalid argument" setting key "kernel.pid_max"
```

Any ideas ?

PS: My kernel is Linux linux-6eea 3.0.101-0.35-pae #1 SMP Wed Jul 9 11:43:04 UTC 2014 (c36987d) i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux

Comment: `My kernel is 0.101-0.35-pae` - no, it's not ;-) please post the output of `uname -a` in your question.

Comment: You could find more information from [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/16884/47538).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The value can only be extended up to a theoretical maximum of 32768 for 32 bit systems or 4194304 for 64 bit.

From `man 5 proc`:

> ```
> /proc/sys/kernel/pid_max  
>   This file (new in Linux 2.5) specifies the value at which PIDs wrap around
>   (i.e., the value in this file is one greater than the maximum PID). The
>   default value for this file, 32768, results in the same range of PIDs as
>   on earlier kernels. On 32-bit platfroms, 32768 is the maximum value for
>   pid_max. On 64-bit systems, pid_max can be set to any value up to 2^22
>   (PID_MAX_LIMIT, approximately 4 million).
> ```

Comment: My arch is x86, meaning 32-bit. So that's why I got this error. Thank you very very much sir.

Comment: It would be helpful to point at an explanation as to where those theoretical maximums come from.

Comment: Debian 9 has default equal to 131072.