# Do I need to reboot LINUX server after changing pid_max?

Tags: linux

I changed the value stored in `/proc/sys/kernel/pid_max`. Do I need to reboot for this new value to take effect?

Comment: How did you change it?

Comment: @JaroslavKucera `echo 999 >/proc/sys/kernel/pid_max`. You can increase or decrease as you wish. A change will affect only newly created processes. You can make the change permanent by inserting a `kernel.pid_max = 999` into your `/etc/sysctl.conf`. Short pids are very handy, long pids look very professional (but they are not). The kernel wired-in max is 32-bit pids, so rougly 4billion. The default is 32766.

Comment: @peterh Thank you, but I wanted to know how Vikas really did it, because modification of /proc/sys/kernel/pid_max isn't permanent. So without modification of sysctl.conf or file in sysctl.d it would be just temporary change.

Answer (score 7):

**Should you have increased `/proc/sys/kernel/pid_max`** (by doing `cat 100000 > /proc/sys/kernel/pid_max` for example), this value is effective right away, **there is no need to reboot.** I never tried to decrease it though<sup>(*)</sup>.

You can test this the following way (that's somewhat ugly, not to be done on a production machine):

```
i=0 ; while [ $i -lt 10000] ; do (echo $i > /dev/null); ((i++)); done; ps ax | grep AnythingUnlikelyToBeUsedAlready
```

`(echo $i > /dev/null)` is just there to create a new pid at each iteration. 10000 was convenient in my test case but you may adjust it. Here, it loops at run #3 as I previously set my `pid_max` as described above:

```
shlublu:~$ i=0 ; while [ $i -lt 10000 ] ; do (echo $i > /dev/null); ((i++)); done; ps ax | grep AnuthingUnlikelyToBeUsedAlready
86880 pts/0    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto AnuthingUnlikelyToBeUsedAlready

shlublu:~$ i=0 ; while [ $i -lt 10000 ] ; do (echo $i > /dev/null); ((i++)); done; ps ax | grep AnuthingUnlikelyToBeUsedAlready
96882 pts/0    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto AnuthingUnlikelyToBeUsedAlready

shlublu:~$ i=0 ; while [ $i -lt 10000 ] ; do (echo $i > /dev/null); ((i++)); done; ps ax | grep AnuthingUnlikelyToBeUsedAlready
 7246 pts/0    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto AnuthingUnlikelyToBeUsedAlready

shlublu:~$ i=0 ; while [ $i -lt 10000 ] ; do (echo $i > /dev/null); ((i++)); done; ps ax | grep AnuthingUnlikelyToBeUsedAlready
17260 pts/0    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto AnuthingUnlikelyToBeUsedAlready

shlublu:~$ i=0 ; while [ $i -lt 10000 ] ; do (echo $i > /dev/null); ((i++)); done; ps ax | grep AnuthingUnlikelyToBeUsedAlready
27262 pts/0    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto AnuthingUnlikelyToBeUsedAlready
```

**But should you restart after having done this you will see that `/proc/sys/kernel/pid_max` will have been restored to its default value** (32768 usually).

To make your setting persistant across restarts you have to edit `/etc/sysctl.conf` and set `kernel.pid_max` accordingly.

For example:

```
kernel.pid_max = 100000
```

**Caveat**: [`pid_max` has boundaries](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/162105/239863) that depend on your system. The value you define should be within these limits.

---

<sup>(*) but *@peterh* did and it works obviously, [see comments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/394774/do-i-need-to-reboot-linux-server-after-changing-pid-max/394790#comment704414_394790).</sup>

Comment: I tried to decrease, works like charm. From now, my PIDs will be reduced to 3 digits :-) Tyvm!

Comment: @peterh Yolo! :)

Comment: Btw, afaik the 32-bit pid support is an option in the kernels roughly 15 years ago, thus it is probably default in most distro kernels roughly a decade ago. Probably even 64-bit support pids wouldn't require too tremendous patches, but nobody needs them.

Comment: @peterh This is probably why the default is still 32768. I suppose that extending that value due to an actual need only happens with very *very* **very** busy machines.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick That's right, I should have said 'expect' instead. I'll edit that right away.