# Why is the maximum PID in a 64-bit Linux system 2^22?

Tags: linux, process

Why not 2^62, or 2^31 or anything else?

[What is the maximum value of the Process ID?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16883/what-is-the-maximum-value-of-the-pid-of-a-process)

Comment: It is? What's your source?

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16883/what-is-the-maximum-value-of-the-pid-of-a-process

Comment: That's very specific to Linux. It does not apply to Unix in general.

Comment: I would have preferred using a full 64 bit integer, that way you could guarantee than they never get reused. Reuse leads to race conditions where the meaning of an ID changes between the time you obtain it and use it.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

It seems to be a purely arbitrary choice. It could be anything, but somebody<sup>1</sup> felt 4 million is enough. [Use the source](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/threads.h#L33):

```
/*
 * A maximum of 4 million PIDs should be enough for a while.
 * [NOTE: PID/TIDs are limited to 2^29 ~= 500+ million, see futex.h.]
 */
#define PID_MAX_LIMIT (CONFIG_BASE_SMALL ? PAGE_SIZE * 8 : \
    (sizeof(long) > 4 ? 4 * 1024 * 1024 : PID_MAX_DEFAULT))
```

The history on git only seems to go back as far as 2005, and the value has been that at least as long.

---

<sup>1</sup>The [manpage](http://man.he.net/man5/proc) says that `/proc/sys/kernel/pid_max` was added in 2.5.34, and looking at the [changelog](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v2.5/ChangeLog-2.5.34), it looks like the *somebody* was [Ingo Molnár](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ingo_Moln%C3%A1r):

```
<mingo@elte.hu>
    [PATCH] pid-max-2.5.33-A0

    This is the pid-max patch, the one i sent for 2.5.31 was botched.  I
    have removed the 'once' debugging stupidity - now PIDs start at 0 again.
    Also, for an unknown reason the previous patch missed the hunk that had
    the declaration of 'DEFAULT_PID_MAX' which made it not compile ...
```

<strike>However, Ingo only added `DEFAULT_PID_MAX`. `PID_MAX_LIMIT` was added by Linus Torvalds in [2.5.37](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v2.5/ChangeLog-2.5.37):</strike>

```
<torvalds@home.transmeta.com>
    Make pid_max grow dynamically as needed.
```

Turns out, I misread the changelog.

The changes are in [the 2.5.37 patchset](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v2.5/patch-2.5.37.xz):

```
diff -Nru a/include/linux/threads.h b/include/linux/threads.h
--- a/include/linux/threads.h   Fri Sep 20 08:20:41 2002
+++ b/include/linux/threads.h   Fri Sep 20 08:20:41 2002
@@ -17,8 +17,13 @@
 #define MIN_THREADS_LEFT_FOR_ROOT 4

 /*
- * This controls the maximum pid allocated to a process
+ * This controls the default maximum pid allocated to a process
  */
-#define DEFAULT_PID_MAX 0x8000
+#define PID_MAX_DEFAULT 0x8000
+
+/*
+ * A maximum of 4 million PIDs should be enough for a while:
+ */
+#define PID_MAX_LIMIT (4*1024*1024)

 #endif
```

That's as far as my search skills get me.

---

Thanks to @hobbs, it seems Ingo is the *somebody* after all. The patch I quoted above was first sent by him. From [the LKML post](https://lkml.org/lkml/2002/9/17/80) accompanying it:

> memory footprint of the new PID allocator scales dynamically with
>   /proc/sys/kernel/pid_max: the default 32K PIDs cause a 4K allocation,
>   a pid_max of 1 million causes a 128K footprint. The current absolute
>   limit for pid_max is 4 million PIDs - this does not cause any
>   allocation in the kernel, the bitmaps are demand-allocated runtime.
>   The pidmap table takes up 512 bytes.

There was a heated discussion about having higher limits, but it seems nothing came out of it in the end.

Comment: You can get a git repo with a deeper history of Linux, suitable for archaeology, using the instructions at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3264283/linux-kernel-historical-git-repository-with-full-history . That turns up a5b5f6a "[PATCH] generic-pidhash-2.5.36-J2, BK-curr" by Ingo Molnar, [viewable here on LWN](https://lwn.net/Articles/10424/).

Comment: @hobbs awesome! So it is from Ingo Molnar after all. I wonder why Linus took ownership in the changelog.

Comment: @muru: I believe BitKeeper doesn't support the distinction between committer and author, that was one of the lessons Linus applied when he designed Git. IIRC, Ingo refused to use BitKeeper, so he sent patches per mail, and they got misattributed in the auto-generated ChangeLogs to the committer, because BitKeeper has no separate notion of authorship. That's my guess anyway.

Comment: @JörgWMittag possible. Now I'm thinking I misread the changelog and that bit might be about a different patch.

Comment: The quote near the end of this answer indicates that the reason for not picking an arbitrarily large value is memory constraints. At 128 KB RAM per 1M PIDs, using even 63 bits (leaving the sign bit) would, if I didn't botch the math, require a million TB of RAM for just the PID table. A little on the high side for current systems.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling there was plenty of argument on LKML about that. An immediate reply by [Andries Brouwer](https://lkml.org/lkml/2002/9/18/58) said using a 2^30 shouldn't be a problem. I'd botched the link to the LKML post in the answer, and fixed it now. Have a read!