# Is there a maximum number of group process ID?

Tags: process, posix

The following post [What is the maximum value of the Process ID?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16883/what-is-the-maximum-value-of-the-process-id) mentions how to get the maximum value for a process ID.

Is the maximum value for a group process ID similar? Or is there another file to find the maximum **group process ID**?

Comment: did you explore the directory for likely candidates?

Answer (score 0):

As the "man 2 setsid" man page describes, every process group leader has the same pid as group id.  So the group id has the same maximum count as the pid, inn the peculiar case that each process is a group leader